# Static compiled error with libevent in Mingw+MSYS

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, libevent

I have written a python script expanded in `winxp` with `mingw+msys` compiled. It will call `libevent` lib. I hope that user don't install more library, so I want to compile it statically, but there are errors. The following is my process to compile and install `libevent`:

```
​./configure -prefix=D:/libevent -enable-static
make
make install
```

I wrote two makefiles and I get the same error.

```
libevent.a(buffer.o):In function 'evbuffer_read':undefined reference to 'WSARecv@28' 
libevent.a(buffer.o):In function 'evbuffer_write_iovec':undefined reference to 'WSASend@28' 
........................
```

Here are the makefiles:

### makefile 1

```
HEAD_PATH_FLAGS=-IC:/Python27/include -ID:/boost/include/boost-1_52 -ID:/libevent/include
LIB_PATH_FLAGS=-LD:/boost/lib -LD:/libevent/lib -LC:/Python27/libs
LIB_FLAGS=-lboost_python-mgw46-s-1_52 -Wl,Bstatic -levent -Wl,Bdynamic -lpython27 -lwsock32
SOURCE=test.o 
all:${SOURCE}
g++ ${HEAD_PATH_FLAGS} ${SOURCE} ${LIB_PATH_FLAG} ${LIB_FLAGS} -fPIC -shared -o test.dll
```

### makefile 2

```
HEAD_PATH_FLAGS=-IC:/Python27/include -ID:/boost/include/boost-1_52 -ID:/libevent/include
LIB_PATH_FLAGS=-LD:/boost/lib -LD:/libevent/lib -LC:/Python27/libs
LIB_FLAGS=-lboost_python-mgw46-s-1_52 -lpython27 -lwsock32
SOURCE=test.o D:/libevent/lib/libevent.a
all:${SOURCE}
g++ ${HEAD_PATH_FLAGS} ${SOURCE} ${LIB_PATH_FLAG} ${LIB_FLAGS} -fPIC -shared -o test.dll
```

Why does this happen? How do I get this to compile without errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should link to `libws2_32.a`, as `WSASend` and `WSARecv` defined there. Add `-lws2_32` to your linker commands.

Comment: @Lol4t0,Thank you.It was compiled successfully.